# Duplicate icon of Wing IDE

Tags: plank, icons

I have a Wing IDE icon in Plank. but a second fuzzy icon appears every time the IDE is opened:

enter image description here

[![Not open][1]][1]

[image: When I open Wing IDE]

I think that is like chrome icon bug. I need modify this file, but I don't know how

[image: file]

Comment: It's similar, but this solution don't work for me.

Comment: Out of 6 answers, which one you have followed? Did you got any errors?